# Under what condition would Array.observe's "add" event trigger?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning about observing Array objects. I found the following surprising:

```
var fooArray = [];
Array.observe(fooArray, function(changes){
    console.log('changes:', changes[0].type);
});
fooArray.push({});
```

results in the type of change being `splice` and not `add`

What methods would result in a change event of type `add`? It would seem to me that pushing a single value on it would be the most likely scenario.

Comment: Changing properties, at least. Adding to the collection is technically splicing, whether you're adding or removing. If you tried `fooArray.f = "whatever";`, you'd see it be for "add"

Comment: The MDN documentation states "Index assignment changes which do not change the length of the array may be reported as update changes"

Would that not fall under an update and not an add? Or only if 'f' does not exist yet?

Comment: Why do you bring that up? Setting properties isn't the same as index assignment

Comment: I see now. It does make some sense, but I guess a bit unintuitive to those uninformed. Feel free to submit it as an answer.

Comment: Well, I was lucky to guess and see that setting properties would trigger the "add" event. I hadn't known, and I'm not sure if it's the only way, so I was hoping for someone else to chime in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [MDN reference](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/observe) is not clear about what circumstances fire each change type. Here is a detailed explanation:

### splice

Covers every change that you would expect to happen in an array. All the following functions trigger it:

- `push()`
- `pop()`
- `shift()`
- `unshift()`
- `splice()`

### update

Triggers if the value of some element changes:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
Array.observe(arr, function (changes) {
    console.dir(changes);
});
arr[0] = 'A'; // triggers 'update'
```

It's worth mentioning that some array functions may also trigger it, like `reverse()`.

### add | delete

As unintuitive as it seems, these types are triggered when a **property** is added to/deleted from the array. For example:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
Array.observe(arr, function (changes) {
    console.dir(changes);
});
arr.foo = 'bar'; // triggers 'add'
delete arr.foo;  // triggers 'delete'
```

*P.S.: See [Jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31016869/778272) on why it behaves like this.*

Comment: The unintuitive part comes from the fact that it extends `Object.observe()`, which defines the add, update and delete actions (amongst others) for properties. Creation and removal of array indices fall under splice.

Answer (score 2):

The change observer is actually implemented in [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), from which `Array` inherits. You can get your expected behaviour when you use [`Object.observe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) instead:

```js
var arr = [];
Object.observe(arr, function(changes) {
  console.log(changes)
});
arr.push({});
```

Output:

```
[
    {"type":"add","object":[{}],"name":"0"},
    {"type":"update","object":[{}],"name":"length","oldValue":0}
]
```

As you can see, two things happen here:

1. An object is added under property 0 (i.e. first element),
2. The length property is updated to reflect the new number of elements.

The [`Array.observe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/observe) groups those two changes together into a single **splice** change; basically, anything that affects the length of an array will fall under this. The **add** and **delete** change types will only be triggered for normal properties, leaving just the **update** change type to work in the same way.

By adjusting the accept type list of `Object.observe()` via the optional third argument, you can confirm this:

```js
var arr = [];
Object.observe(arr, function(changes) {
  console.log(changes)
}, ['add', 'update', 'delete', 'splice']);
arr.push({});
```

Output:

```
[
    {"type":"splice","object":[{}],"index":0,"removed":[],"addedCount":1}
]
```

In fact, `Array.observe()` can be implemented like this:

```
Array.observe = function(arr, callback) {
    return Object.observe(arr, callback, ["add", "update", "delete", "splice"]);
};
```

As such, the following change types aren't sent to your callback when you use `Array.observe()`:

```
["reconfigure", "setPrototype", "preventExtensions"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting custom properties such as `arr.b = 1` it is also possible, at least currently using V8 in Node, Opera or Chrome, to trigger "add" changes on Array using:

```
arr = []
arr[1] = 1 // "splice" change
arr[0] = 1 // "add" change
```